# Bootstrap Navbar Background not working properly when responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i am trying to create a website for my uni project with bootstrap 5, but the background color dissappears on the right site on smaller dimension when responsive. I think this is a problem of bg-body-tertiary and changing it to a different background, as when its not changed, it looks normal, even on smaller dimenson below 160px.

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bn0P.jpg)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FydM.jpg)

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xS7r.jpg)

Comment: Based on the information in your screenshot, it appears that a width of 95px is not typically associated with real mobile devices. Most mobile devices tend to have widths starting from around 300px and above.

Comment: Please add relevant code instead of the post Image